# Modify sequence at index using Monocle

Tags: scala, monocle-scala

I can modify Map using `focus` and `index` just fine. Is there a similar functionality in [Monocle](https://www.optics.dev/Monocle/) to update a sequence at given index?

```
import monocle.syntax.all._

case class C(member: Int)

val map = Map(0 -> C(0), 1 -> C(1))
case class MapContainer(seq: Map[Int, C])
val containedMap = MapContainer(map)
containedMap.focus(_.seq).index(0).replace(C(10)) // works fine

val seq = IndexedSeq(C(0), C(1), C(2))
case class Container(seq: IndexedSeq[C])
val containedSeq = Container(seq)

containedSeq.focus(_.seq).index(0).replace(C(10)) // does not compile
```

The error is `Could not find an instance of Index[IndexedSeq[C],Int,A1]`.

Is such functionality available for Monocle? I was using [Quicklens](https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens) previously and it used `at` for both maps and sequences. Unfortunately Quicklens Scala 3 support is not very good at this point, therefore I am exploring alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see `.index` relies on [`Index` instance](https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle/blob/b2520b237fa6c0412c20425ee3040a81e8b452a2/core/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/function/Index.scala#L27) which should be available for the type that you want to apply index to.

If you modify your code to this:

```
val seq = IndexedSeq(C(0), C(1), C(2))
case class Container(seq: List[C]) // List instead of IndexedSeq
val containedSeq = Container(seq.toList)

containedSeq.focus(_.seq).index(0).replace(C(10))
```

it does compile.

So the issue is lack of instance for `IndexedSeq`. Among the build-in instances for standard data types you can see:

```
  implicit def seqIndex[A, S[B] <: SeqOps[B, S, S[B]]]: Index[S[A], Int, A] // this should work
  implicit def listIndex[A]: Index[List[A], Int, A]
  implicit def lazyListIndex[A]: Index[LazyList[A], Int, A]
  implicit def listMapIndex[K, V]: Index[ListMap[K, V], K, V]
  implicit def mapIndex[K, V]: Index[Map[K, V], K, V]
  implicit def sortedMapIndex[K, V]: Index[SortedMap[K, V], K, V]
  implicit val stringIndex: Index[String, Int, Char]
  implicit def vectorIndex[A]: Index[Vector[A], Int, A]
```

but from what I see `seqIndex` was [added 2 months ago](https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle/commit/b2520b237fa6c0412c20425ee3040a81e8b452a2) and not released yet (3.1.0 was released a year ago).

So your best bet is to use some specific data structure or implement this implicit yourself.